Get image dimensions with NEXT JS before image has fully loaded
    <Image
                            src={gallery.image}
                            alt={`Image ${gallery.id + 1}`}
                            width={500}
                            height={500}
                            objectFit="cover"
                            priority
                            onLoadingComplete={({ naturalWidth, naturalHeight }) =>
                                handleImageLoad(gallery.image, naturalWidth, naturalHeight)
                            }
                            className="h-[418px] w-full object-cover hover:cursor-pointer"
                        />

const handleImageLoad = (src: string, width: number, height: number) => {
setImageDimensions((prev) => ({
...prev,
[src]: { width, height }
}))
}
const handleImageLoad = (src: string, width: number, height: number) => {
setImageDimensions((prev) => ({
...prev,
[src]: { width, height }
}))
}
I have searched for different resources available online but couldn't find it, Hope there's someone who can help me in this. I am building a photo grid where I want the image to be loaded before the loading is completed. I mean the remote width and height which I should get by destructuring the source. I have found it in javascript where do solve it using setTimeout and stuffs but couldn't find in NEXT JS.

can i ask what is your purpose of getting width and height of a image?

To display the image in grid layout      if (width > column3Width) {
return sm:col-span-1 md:col-span-3
} else if (width > column2Width) {
return sm:col-span-1 md:col-span-2
} else {
return sm:col-span-1 md:col-span-1
}

I will explain you in better way , I dont't have width and height  property in the api that is to be fetched, So I first loaded the image and destructured the image height and width from the image src itself, Now the problem is that there is a slght blank page issue when reload for like 1 second,which is causing performance optimization issue. I am using onLoadComplete image property of Next JS Image which helps to retrieve the height and width from the src image after it loads completely,But I want a way to retrieve the image height and width before reload

did you tried min-width to prevent blank space? because there is no way to get image width and height before it fully loaded unless you get it from a server.

if you want that in server, you can create a proxy for your api. call the api in your server and calculate all images width and height and then return that with calculated dimensions. btw it is a high cost process.

Yes using server components either way its costly so decided to use some loader effects to handle it, Thanks for the suggestion mate. !! \
